# How should I show list of array colors in a <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I am a newbie, and I am not sure how to achieve what I want. Well, I have this piece of code, which I am learning currently.

```
var color = ["#AAAAAA" , "#FF9992", "#BF9232"];
$("#button1").click(function() {
  // I have a print a the colors in array in <select><option>

});
```

On clicking the button I would like to create a `<select>` tag with all the colours in the array, populated with the `<option>`'s background colour being the value of the colour.

I am not sure how I could proceed. All I know is it can be done using jQuery as the array is dynamic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of the array. Use this way:

```js
var color = ["#AAAAAA" , "#FF9992", "#BF9232"];
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("div").append("<select />");
  var html = "";
  color.map(function (clr) {
    html += '<option style="background: ' + clr + ';">' + clr + '</option>';
  });
  $("select").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<div></div>
```

If you want the `<select>` to change the background colour based on the `<option>`, then you can do this:

```js
var color = ["#AAAAAA" , "#FF9992", "#BF9232"];
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("div").append("<select />");
  var html = "";
  color.map(function (clr) {
    html += '<option style="background: ' + clr + ';">' + clr + '</option>';
  });
  $("select").append(html).change(function () {
    $(this).css("background", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The first answer u gave me answered by question. Is there more ways to make it more efficient?

Comment: Thanks, bro. i didn't know to able to set any colors to options

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Yes, it has less support.

Comment: @TEniDign This is a decent and efficient way AFAIK.

Comment: Do we even need the **$("div").append("<select />");** ?

Comment: Could u please explain what **$("div").append("<select />"); $("select").append(html);**  are doing

Comment: what does **<select />** mean? I have seen <select> </select>

Comment: @TEniDign First one appends **to** div, the select tag. Second one appends **to** select tag, the generated option htmls.

Comment: Self closing select tag. `:)` A select tag with its closing tag on the opening tag itself.

Comment: is it good idea to put a id in the select tag? so that it will take less time for js to do the function? Since **$("select").append(html)** means all the select tag?

Comment: I answer with other way. If it helps i'm very glad

Answer (score 1):

I suggest other solution with plain JavaScript.

```js
var color = ["#AAAAAA" , "#FF9992", "#BF9232"];

function addOptions(arr, selectId) {
    var s = document.getElementById(selectId);
    if (!s) {
        s = document.createElement("select");
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("box");
        myDiv.appendChild(s);

        s.id = selectId;
    }
    s.options.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = arr[i];
        option.style.backgroundColor = arr[i];
        option.value = arr[i];
        s.options[s.options.length] = option;
    }
}


document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    addOptions(color, "second");
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nice... This is pure JavaScript way.